# Do something if position is less than X. Jquery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, prepend

```
$("#rightControl").click(function(){
    $("#thumb_menu").animate({"left": "-=520px"}, "slow");
    var pos = $('#thumb_menu').position();
    if(pos.left < 0) { 
        $('#header')
            .prepend('<span class="control" id="leftControl">Move left</span>')
}
});
```

Clicking `#rightControl` once moves `#thumb_menu` to -450px left so the `if` should run but I cant seem to get this working.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place it in a callback to the `.animate()` so that it has a chance to change its position before the `.position()` method is invoked..

```
$("#rightControl").click(function () {
    $("#thumb_menu").animate({
        "left": "-=520px"
    }, "slow", function() {
        var pos = $(this).position();
        if (pos.left < 0) {
            $('#header').prepend('<span class="control" id="leftControl">Move left</span>')
        }
    });
});
```

Although if you know it is moving to a negative position, I wouldn't think you'd need the `if()` statement at all. Just do the `.prepend()` in the callback.

Comment: Thank you patrick dw. Works great. I need the if statement because this is just a small part of a larger script. I need to know when the div is on or off the edge of another div.

Comment: @3rror404: You're welcome. If you need more precise determination of when it is off the edge, the `.animate()` method has a `step:` callback that is fired for each update during the animation. If so, replace the `"slow", function() {...}` with `{duration:"slow",step:function(){...}`.

Answer (score 0):

The position method is relative to the document, not the element's original position:
http://api.jquery.com/position/

So `.position()` will only be `< 0` if the element is actually off the screen. What you should do is capture the original position of the element before you move it and then see if it's less than that.